# Simple connectedness of basin of attraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, connectedness, chaos-theory, maximum-principle, basins-of-attraction

I want to prove that the immediate basin of attraction of a finite attracting fixed or periodic point is simply connected. We are talking about complex numbers !
According to Remark 2 p. 281 and Exercise 4.2 p. 283 of the text of Devaney [[1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CjAnY99LwTgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)],

> If $z_0$ is a finite attracting orbit (i.e., $z_0 \neq +\infty$), then any component of its basin of attraction is simply connected. This fact is an easy consequence of the Maximum Principle (see Exercise 4.2).
>
> **Exercise 4.2.**
>   Prove that the immediate attracting basin of a (finite) attracting periodic
>   point is simply connected.

Apparently easy so I must be overlooking something.
Who can give me an accurate proof ?

---

[[1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CjAnY99LwTgC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_atb#v=onepage&q&f=false)] Robert L. Devaney, *An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems*, 2nd ed., Westview Press, 2003.

Comment: By definition, the immediate basin of attraction is the connected component of the basin of attraction containing $P$ and so is connected. Your question is about it being  *simply* connected. You may want to improve the title to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be rigorous then I don't think it is that easy (but I am not a real  expert in the domain).
One possible approach is to use two
 topological results:

Lemma 1: If $A\subset \widehat{\Bbb C}$ (the Riemann sphere) is connected then each connected component of $ \widehat{\Bbb C}\setminus A$ is simply connected. (more or less obvious)

You may use this in the following way:
Let $\gamma: [0,1]\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$, $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)$ be a continuous map (a loop). Let $\Omega\subset \widehat{\Bbb C}$ be the connected component  of $\widehat {\Bbb C}\setminus \gamma$ containing $\infty$. We define $\Phi(\gamma) =  \widehat{\Bbb C}\setminus \Omega$ to be its compliment. By the above lemma, both $\Omega$ and (more interestingly here) $\Phi(\gamma)\subset {\Bbb C}$ are simply connected.
Furthermore, $\partial \Phi(\gamma) \subset \gamma$.
The set $\Phi(\gamma)$ contains intuitively the points "encircled by $\gamma$".

The second topological result comes from the maximum principle.

Lemma 2: If $D\subset {\Bbb C}$ is a bounded domain and $f:{\Bbb C}\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$ is analytic then $\partial f (D) \subset f (\partial D)$, i.e. the image of the boundary contains the boundary of the image.

To see this, note that if $w_0=f(z_0)\in \partial f(D)$, $z_0\in D$ but $w_0$ is not in $f(\partial D)$ then you get a contradiction with the maximum principle for the function $z\in D \mapsto 1/(f(z)-w)$ by choosing $w$ close enough to $w_0$ but in the complement of $f(D)$.

Now, let $p$ be an attractive fixed point of a periodic point of an entire map $f:{\Bbb C}\rightarrow {\Bbb C}$ (or some iterate of it in the case of a periodic point). 
Let $\gamma$ be a loop consisting of points in a basin of attraction of $p$ (possibly the immediate basin but it need not be) and define as above $D=\Phi(\gamma)$.

By the two Lemmas $$ \partial f^n (D) \subset f^n(\partial D) \subset f^n(\gamma)$$
which implies that $f^n(D)$ converges to $p$ since $f^n (\gamma)$ does. Thus, $D$ belongs to the same basin of attraction as $\gamma$ and since $D$ is simply connected so is the basin.

Comment: Your explanation of lemma 2 (to see this....) is to compact for me. I tried to write our a complete proof, but I don't see the crucial contradiction. I can follow the overall idea of your complete answer but I really wonder is this is what Devaney meant by "EASY consequence" in his text.

Comment: Choose $w$ in the complement of $f(D)$ so that $0<|w_0-w|<r < R < |f(z)-w|$ for all $z\in \partial D$. Then $g(z)=1/(f(z)-w)$ is analytic on $\bar{D}$ but $|g(z_0)|> 1/r > 1/R > \max\{ |g(z)|: z\in \partial D\}$ contradicting the max principle. There are btw other easy ways to see this: A non-constant analytic map is "open" so is $B(z,r)\subset D$ then $f(B(z,r))$ is an open neighborhood of $f(z)$ which therefore can not be a boundary point. Devaney's use of 'easy' is perhaps not so appropriate in this context (unless he has proven something similar before in the book?)

Comment: In my view Devaney did'n't proof anything similar, so your proof is the definite answer to my question !

Comment: I also had a look in Carleson-Gamelin "Complex dynamics". They also just state this result somewhere as a consequence of the max principle without further details. A bit fast, in my opinion.

Comment: I just bought that book ! Can you give me the pages where you looked ? Maybe a nice start for me to continue my study of complex dynamics !

Comment: The book is very nice but not that easy. In my 1993 edition, there are special cases mentioned in chap III p 55 3rd example and p 59 Thm 2.2 (this one avoids the max principle through other arguments), and then in chap IV p 70 Thm 1.1 (which b.t.w. mentions the content of my Lemma 1, without proof) and p 71 Thm 1.3 (of Sullivan) where more or less the full statement appears (with few details, as it is just preliminary to proving something else).